# ProGuard only obfuscates methods and not package/ fragment/activity names

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, decompiling, dex

```
    minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


-flattenpackagehierarchy 'myobfuscated'
-repackageclasses 'myobfuscated'
-allowaccessmodification
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity/Fragment names must not be obfuscated. Activity names are included in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and it exposes an app's Activities which is usual to launch intent/functionalities from outside of the app. Fragment names are required when you use Fragment names in your layout xmls in fragment holders or `FragmentContainerView`. Hence, they are excluded from being obfuscated.